# Android stacked views

Tags: android

The view that I would like to have would be shown in the figure.

[image: example]

Comment: It it recommended that you want to use canvas ?? If not then use RelativeLayout. .  it will help you to make such type of view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For that you can take [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).

**For example - 1:**

```
 <FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView 
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Learn-Android.com"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

### Update:

**For Example - 2: Superb example and Trick, found here: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/golden_gate" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

        android:padding="12dip"

        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"

        android:text="Golden Gate" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the 2 custom views inside a relative layout will give what you've shown in the image.

Yes the customview2 will be transparent in the areas where you don't draw anything. To avoid that you will need to set a background to that view.